flutter not recognized by command prompt
I'm just installed android studio, and I tried setting my environment variable several times. I even put it under the System Variables list as well as the User variables list. Please Help. I am on a Windows 11 PC.
I tried command prompt, github cmd, powershell, and searched online for 30 minutes straight, but couldn't find the answer.

Have you tried turning it off and on again? :P
Seriously though, if you have (correctly) added it to the Env vars, try a restart

Follow these steps:

Extract flutter zip file.
Open start menu and search for "Environment variables" and open "Edit environment variables for your account"
Double click on "Path" in the "User variables" section.
Click on "New" and write full path of your flutter "bin" folder, example: if you extract flutter into C:\flutter, then you need to enter C:\flutter\bin here.
Save and restart your pc, it should be work now.

